# filter function is ignored when attempting to search an array by a search term

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to write a similar function to this to filter a large array based on a search term:

```
function my_func(my_list, term) {
    my_list.filter(function(card){
    if(card.includes(term)){
        return card;
    }
    else {
      return  "something else"
    }
    })
  return "inside"
}

const my_list = ["merloc", "spider", "orc",  "wisp", "giant"]

my_func(my_list, "wisp")
```

However `card` is never returned. In fact not even "something else" is returned - the only result is "inside".
How can I get the above function to return `card` based on the search term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small fix add return before my_list.filter

```
function my_func(my_list, term) {
  return my_list.filter(function(card){
    if(card.includes(term)){
       return card;
    }
    else {
       return  "something else"
    }
 })
 return "inside"
}

const my_list = ["merloc", "spider", "orc",  "wisp", "giant"]

my_func(my_list, "wisp")
```